# Storing a property in an instance variable or use a method to calculate it?

Tags: java, methods, instance-variables

The first time I came across this was as such: a `Box` class with a list that contains items. All these items have an `int weight` instance variable. Now, to get the weight of the `Box`, should one use an instance variable `weight` to keep track of this? Or should you use a method `calculateWeight()` to get the weight?

```
public class Box {
    private ArrayList<Item> list; // Item objects in the list, all Item objects have a weight
    private int weight; // Should I: use an instance variable as is seen here <- ?

    public int calculateWeight() { // or use a method to calculate the weight each time?
       int sum = 0;
       // for all items get the weight and add it together
       return sum;
    }
}
```

Now in this example, it makes more sense to me to use a method rather than an instance variable, because otherwise the instance variable `weight` of the `Box` would have to be updated each time an item is added or removed.

But now I am working on a readability score calculator (project on JetBrains), and I find it less obvious what I am supposed to do. The readability score calculator takes a text and finds the amount of sentences, words, chars, syllables etc. and uses a simple formula to calculate a readability score. For now, I have been storing all the amounts of sentences, words, chars etc. in instance variables by calling the methods for calculating each inside the constructor, but I am not sure whether this is a good practice or not (It feels somewhat cluttered to me). An alternative would be to simply not store them in instance variables and only use the methods to obtain the amounts each time you need them. This is what the code looks like right now:

```
public abstract class ReadabilityScoreCalculator {
    protected String name;
    protected String text;
    protected int wordCount;
    protected int sentenceCount;
    protected int charCount;
    protected int syllableCount;
    protected int polySyllableCount;
    protected double score;
    protected int age;

    public ReadabilityScoreCalculator(String text, String name) {
        this.text = text;
        this.name = name;
        this.wordCount = this.countWords();
        this.sentenceCount = this.countSentences();
        this.charCount = this.countCharacters();
        this.syllableCount = this.countSyllables();
        this.polySyllableCount = this.countPolySyllables();
        this.score = this.calculateAndReturnScore();
        this.age = this.getAgeGroup();
    }

     private int countWords() {
        return this.getArrayOfWords().length;
    }

     private String[] getArrayOfWords() {
         return this.text.split("[ ]+");
     }

    private int countSentences() {
        return this.text.split("[.!?]").length;
    }

    private int countCharacters() {
        String textWithoutSpaces = this.removeSpaces();
        return textWithoutSpaces.length();
    }

    private String removeSpaces() {
        return this.text.replaceAll("[ ]+", "");
    }

    private int countSyllables() {
        String[] words = this.getArrayOfWords();
        int amountOfSyllables = Arrays.stream(words)
                .mapToInt(word -> this.countSyllablesInWord(word))
                .reduce(0, (previousCount, amountOfSyllablesInWord) -> previousCount + amountOfSyllablesInWord);
        return amountOfSyllables;
    }


    private int countSyllablesInWord(String word) {
        int amountOfSyllablesInWord = 0;
        for (int i = 0, n = word.length(); i < n; i++) {
            char character = word.charAt(i);
            if (this.isCharVowel(character)) {
                if (this.isCharVowel(word.charAt(i - 1)) || this.areWeAtTheLastCharAndDoesItEqualE(i, word)) {
                    continue;
                }
                amountOfSyllablesInWord++;
            }
        }
        return (amountOfSyllablesInWord == 0) ? 1 : amountOfSyllablesInWord;
    }

    private boolean isCharVowel(char character) {
        String charAsString = String.valueOf(character);
        return charAsString.matches("(?i)[aeiouy]");
    }

    private boolean areWeAtTheLastCharAndDoesItEqualE(int index, String word) {
        int wordLength = word.length();
        char currentCharacter = word.charAt(index);
        return (index == (wordLength - 1) && currentCharacter == 'e');
    }

    private int countPolySyllables() {
        String[] words = this.getArrayOfWords();
        int amountOfPolySyllables = Arrays.stream(words)
                .mapToInt(word -> this.countSyllablesInWord(word))
                .filter(amountOfSyllablesInWord -> amountOfSyllablesInWord > 2)
                .reduce(0, (previousCount, amountOfPolySyllablesInWord) -> previousCount + amountOfPolySyllablesInWord);
        return amountOfPolySyllables;
    }

    private double calculateAndReturnScore() {
        return this.calculateScore();
    }

    abstract double calculateScore();

    public void setScore(double score) {
        this.score = score;
    }

    public void printResults() {
        System.out.println(this.name + ": " + this.score + " (about " + this.age + " year olds).");
    }

    public void setAgeGroup() {
        this.age = this.getAgeGroup();
    }

    private int getAgeGroup() {
        int ageGroup = 0;
        switch(this.roundUpAndParseToInt(this.score)) {
            case 1:
                ageGroup = 6;
                break;
            case 2:
                ageGroup = 7;
                break;
            case 3:
                ageGroup = 9;
                break;
            case 4:
                ageGroup = 10;
                break;
            case 5:
                ageGroup = 11;
                break;
            case 6:
                ageGroup = 12;
                break;
            case 7:
                ageGroup = 13;
                break;
            case 8:
                ageGroup = 14;
                break;
            case 9:
                ageGroup = 15;
                break;
            case 10:
                ageGroup = 16;
                break;
            case 11:
                ageGroup = 17;
                break;
            case 12:
                ageGroup = 18;
                break;
            case 13:
                ageGroup = 24;
                break;
            case 14:
                ageGroup = 24;
                break;
        }
        return ageGroup;
    }

    public int roundUpAndParseToInt(double number) {
        return (int) Math.ceil(number);
    }


}
```

Is one or the other considered good practice or not? Or does it really depend on the situation? I can see that the method way would be more computationally expensive, but gives more certainty. Any other problems with my code above may also be called out.

Edit: this is an abstract class, and the `calculateScore()` method is supposed to be filled in by the class inheriting from this one. As such, multiple different formulas to calculate the readability score can be used.

Answer (score 0):

In general, omit using calculation-based instance variables in favor of methods for retrieval. More important is whether your code documents itself concisely and is easy to maintain.

By using instance variables, you will need to update them every time their respective properties are modified, and this can muddy the readability of your methods that modify these variables.

For example, here's a few simple methods that modify `list` and update the `weight` member variable:

```
public void addItem(Item item) {
    this.list.add(item);
    this.weight += item.weight;
}

public Item removeItem(int i) {
    Item item = this.list.remove(i);
    this.weight -= item.weight;
    return item;
}

public void setList(ArrayList<Item> list) {
    this.list = list;
    this.weight = this.calculateWeight();
}
```

Because you're performing an additional operation that is *not* described in the method name, these methods are not self-documenting. You could instead call them something like `addItemAndUpdateWeight()`, but what if there are many more member variables to update? `addItemAndUpdateMemberVariables()` is too vague, and very quickly these methods will get very messy and hard to maintain.

You *could* add a helper function to update your member variables, but you'd still need to call it in every such method, and every time you add a new member variable you'll have to update this method, too.

Plus, if these methods are expensive, it's better to perform the calculations only when needed.

A better solution is to keep it simple by isolating the functionality of your methods:

```
public void addItem(Item item) {
    this.list.add(item);
}

public Item removeItem(int i) {
    return this.list.remove(i);
}

public void setList(ArrayList<Item> list) {
    this.list = list;
}
```

Immediately, you know exactly what these methods do, and there's no sneaky code to cause headaches for you later. Plus, now you don't need to perform these operations in your constructor.

I'm sure a case could be made for more complex situations like indexing, but this seems outside the scope of this discussion.

Comment: So the solution would be to have a method called getWeight() (which loops through all items and adds up the weight) that you can call whenever you need to get the weight of the entire box?

Comment: @ReefG yes. You likely don't need to access the weight as often as you add and remove items, so it's not necessary to perform this calculation every time the box's contents change.